# How to delete mail form sent folder after sending?

Tags: email, vbscript

I am currently writing code using vbscript to automate sending of email.
How do I delete that very same email that I sent in the sent folder?

Below is my code:

```
Dim ToAddress
Dim FromAddress
Dim MessageSubject
Dim MyTime
Dim MessageBody
Dim MessageAttachment
Dim ol, ns, newMail

ToAddress = "site.net"
MessageSubject = "stuff"
MessageBody = "SEND" 

MessageAttachment = "C:\Users\Bellere\Desktop\numbers.csv"

Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.getNamespace("MAPI")
Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody & vbCrLf
newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress)
newMail.Attachments.Add(MessageAttachment)
newMail.Send
```

Any help is appericated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this and this should do for the first occurrence of the sent item from the script

```
Const olMailItem = 0
Const olFolderSentMail = 5
Dim ToAddress
Dim FromAddress
Dim MessageSubject
Dim MyTime
Dim MessageBody
Dim MessageAttachment
Dim ol, ns, newMail
Dim oMail ' <- added

ToAddress = "site.net"
MessageSubject = "stuff"
MessageBody = "SEND" 

MessageAttachment = "C:\Users\Bellere\Desktop\numbers.csv"

Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.getNamespace("MAPI")
Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody & vbCrLf
newMail.RecipIents.Add(ToAddress)
newMail.Attachments.Add(MessageAttachment)
newMail.Send

' Search for the first occurrence of the sent item (Subject and first recipient address)
Set newMail = Nothing
For Each oMail In ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
    If oMail.Subject = MessageSubject And oMail.Recipients(1).Address = ToAddress Then
        Set newMail = oMail
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not newMail Is Nothing Then newMail.Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

This section describes how to use the Microsoft Outlook 11.0 Object Library to Delete messages from the Outlook Inbox in Visual Basic .NET.

```
Dim tempApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim tempSent As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SentItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim tempMail As Object
    tempApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    tempSent = tempApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)
    SentItems = tempSent.Items
    Dim DeleteMail As Outlook.MailItem
    For Each newMail In SentItems
        DeleteMail.Delete()
    Next
```

**Note** : *The most improtant point here to performing all tasks is to add a reference to "Microsoft Outlook object library", In case of*

```
 Microsoft Outlook 2000, Add "Microsoft Outlook 9.0 object library" 
 Microsoft Outlook 2002, Add "Microsoft Outlook 10.0 object library" 
 Microsoft Outlook 2003, Add "Microsoft Outlook 11.0 object library" 
 Microsoft Outlook 2007, Add "Microsoft Outlook 12.0 object library"
```

Comment: OP bellere is seeking for VBS code, not VBA. No references - need create `Const` for the Outlook internal values.